# Sequence of functions that converges strongly in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but not pointwise

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces, pointwise-convergence, strong-convergence

I am trying to find a sequence of functions $\{f_j\}$ and a function $f$ such that $f_j\to f$ strongly in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but $f_j$ does not converge to $f$ pointwise. The definition of strong convergence I am given is:

> $f_j\to f$ strongly in $L^2$ if there exists $f\in L^2\mathbb R$ such that $$||f_j-f||_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\to0$$

Now I am not interested at all in a full solution to this, I already have it and am choosing not to look at it. Rather, I'd like to know how one would approach a problem like this. Should I start by defining an inner product to find the norm, so as to at least gain intuition for what the norm represents? Should I just start trying common functions and 'tweak' as appropriate? Should I instead write out the epsilon-delta definition of a limit and try to expand from there using norm properties? Should I just try all of those? How does one even know where to start?

Usually, I can develop some intuition for the problem but inner products in a space need not be unique so the abstractness makes it much harder for me I find.

Comment: You are over-thinking. Don't pay much attention to the norm, inner product etc. to think of a counter-example. There is a standard example of  a sequence which converges in measure but not almost everywhere. The same sequence works here too.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not sure what "converges in measure" and "not almost everywhere" means. I did some research and everything I found seems to mention some sequence $\chi$ with an interval specified as a subscript, I don't know what that means either.

Comment: Look up "typewriter sequence".  By the way, $\chi_A$ is standard notation; when $A$ is a set, it means a function that takes the value 1 on $A$ and 0 elsewhere.  Some authors write it as $1_A$ instead.

Comment: The typewriter sequence that Nate mentions is the best example. Note also that you asked for a sequence that doesn’t converge pointwise so, strictly speaking the constant sequence $f_n=\mathcal{X}_{\{0\}}$ would also work.

Comment: @JonathanHole The second sequence that you mention: $f_n=\chi_{[0]}$. That means that it takes the value $1$ at $0$, and $0$ elsewhere, right (based on what Nate Eldredge said)? But since every term is the same, wouldn't it converge pointwise?

Answer (score 1):

On $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure consider the sequence

$X_1=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$

$X_1=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}$, $X_3=\mathbb{}_{[1/2,1]}$,

$X_4=\mathbb{1}_{[1,1/4]}$, $X_5=\mathbb{1}_{[1/4,2/4]}$,$X_6=\mathbb{1}_{[2/4,3/4]}$, $X_7=\mathbb{1}_{[3/4,1]}$.

... see the pattern?

Once can see that $\|X_n\|_2\rightarrow0$ (the subintervals get smaller and smaller) but $0=\liminf_nX_n(t)<\limsup_nX_n(t)=1$ for all $t$ (like the typewriter got from one en of a line to the other)

Comment: What does the cursive B mean? And I've never heard of measures before, so I'm not sure what Lebesgue's measure is. Finally, what does the subscript 2 mean on the last line?

Comment: The Borel $sigma$--algebra on $[0,1]$. It contains all intervals so that one can consider their indicator functions as "random variables"